# Database Connection error: Invalid database name

Tags: postgresql, arccatalog, connection

I just created a new database in my Postres called GlenMary and I can't get ArcMap to connect through my already established database connection in ArcMap. I am trying to add some new data to the database but I keep getting an error when I try to connect.
[image: GlenMary database]

Even though I can connect to the database below it ("beauregard"-highlighted), and the database name validates and populates in the database dropdown, when I click "OK" I get the following error. Any idea how to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a note in the [doc](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/setup-geodatabase-postgresql-windows.htm):

> Type the database name in lowercase; upper- and mixed-case object
>   names are not supported for geodatabases in PostgreSQL. If you type a
>   database name in upper or mixed case, ArcGIS converts it to lower
>   case.

so you may want to rename your DB.

Comment: Well, your answer is totally correct. I was able to connect once I changed the name to lowercase without any issues.